# Predict the probabilty of a value belonging to a particular class

Tags: probability-distributions, regression, logistic-regression

I have got two classes : `BG` and `FG` and a set of values assigned to each of these classes. Given a new value how can I find whether that value belongs to `FG` or `BG`?. Should I train a classifier (Logistic regression) to do the job or is there any other probabilitic method?

Comment: If you know explicity what is the set of values for each class, then naturally only compares the new value with both sets. Can you explain better your question?

Comment: @sinbadh :but the new value might not be in any explicit sets.

Comment: Puff... your ask is very general. The classic method for clasification is not probabilistic. It is named perceptron. The idea is that, if you have, for example, two classes BG and FG, find the "better line" that separates the two sets. Then, it is easly to classify the new observation

Comment: thanks but what I need is the probability of a value belonging to both the classes

Comment: Then you will try with a hypothesis testing